# Check if number is in hex format and convert it to decimal

Tags: shell

I run a shell script in Ubuntu with the following line to extract a number from a text line as shown below. It is an xml file, and I am looking for a number in the field "show". The problem is that the number in the field "show" in the xml file is sometimes given as hex and sometimes as decimal. My question is how to modify the script line to check if the nr is in hex format and convert it to decimal? I want the result to be always decimal no matter in what format is the number in the field "show" in.Ideally in one line if possible.

```
cellid=`cat /tmp/cellid.txt |awk -F"show=" '{print $2}'| cut -d"\"" -f2|cut -d"(" -f3| sed 's/)//g'

<field name="gsm_a.lac" showname="Location Area Code (LAC): 0xe54c (58700)" size="2" pos="66" show="0x0000e54c" value="e54c"/>
```

Comment: How do you know what base the input number is in?  Are hex numbers always preceded by `0x`?

Comment: Yes, 0x prefix denotes a hex number. Decimal number is just digits.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing `awk` and `regex`, I recommend you to use [xmllint](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html) to parse `xml`.

To install on ununtu:

```
 sudo apt-get install libxml2-utils
```

To covert hex or decimal to decimal, use `$(())` in bash.

**DEMO**

```
lo@ubuntu:~$ cat xx.xml
<field name="gsm_a.lac" showname="Location Area Code (LAC): 0xe54c (58700)" size="2" pos="66" show="0x0000e54c" value="e54c"/>
lo@ubuntu:~$ id=$(($(xmllint --xpath '//field/@show' xx.xml| grep -Po '".*"?' | tr -d \")))
lo@ubuntu:~$ echo $id
58700

lo@ubuntu:~$ echo $((0x11))
17
lo@ubuntu:~$ echo $((11))
11
lo@ubuntu:~$ echo $((011))
9
```

Comment: Using xmllint is a good idea. there are some problems with this answer however. The line of text from my example is only one of many lines in the file, so how do I feed xmllint with the right lines? Second, for some reason my xml file doesn't start with "<" and xmllint gets confused. Another problem is that $((11)) and $((011)) return different result. This is unacceptable. To me both should return 11 decimal. I have no idea where 9 comes from.

Comment: Well, you have to provide the full xml file. Anyway, it's not a good idea to parse a xml file in a "regex"  way.  The idea of using `xml` parser to parse a xml file is just a direction. The complete answer depend on your complete problem, maybe you should read the xmllint doc to figure out the   complete solution to your problem.